# Apache is showing another virtualhost when accessed with IP

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am running apache server on ubuntu 14.04. I have added a couple of virtual hosts on `/var/www`. When I open my server IP on chrome, its showing one of my virtual hosts and not the content on `/var/www/html`.

Apache config is:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName MYSERVERIP
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>

        Servername mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com
        <Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: VirtualHost tags are added but the post is not showing them.

Comment: Any error messages in any of the logs???

Comment: @RiggsFolly It was ok. The problem was with my browser's cache. thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem on my brower's cache and it didn't get updated. The config is fine.